# ASP.NET Core publish produces lots of DLLs in the published folder, why?

Tags: asp.net, windows, asp.net-core, .net-core

I created a simple Web API project in Visual Studio 2015 using the .NET Core Framework.  When I publish this project using the default settings, it creates the following:

[image]

In total there are **155 DLLs**, 77 in the PublishOutput root and 78 in the refs folder.

- Why put all the DLLs in the publish folder?  Couldn't it just
  reference the DLLs where they were installed from a single shared
  location ?

Comment: Folder contains your original application structure plus all the nuget dependency assemblies dumped.

Comment: @M. Wiśnicki, my question was more on why it does it, I can understand if it is a 3rd party dependency but wouldn't these DLL's be part of the .NET Core framework ?  I guess I'm a little confused as to why there are 155 separate DLLs needed for a simple Web API project and I thought I must have not configured it correctly ?

Comment: you can opt in or out of dependencies. it is very modular only what you depned on from project.json is included with your app. the old monolithic way where framework had to be installed on the web host machine meant that you could not get an updated version of a dependency without the host machine installing updates. with a big monolith like that updates were infrequent. you can even deploy the runtime with your app so it doesn't depend on what version of the runtime is installed on the web host

Comment: @JoeAudette in the default .NET Core Web API project that Visual Studio creates the project.json file does not have 155 DLLs defined.  I do see handful of dependencies defined, so what your saying then is that those dependencies are packages that require all those DLLs, all 155 of them ?  Also, is it possible to opt in and opt out of DLLs or is that only possible at the dependency/package level ?

Comment: some dependencies have other dependencies of their own, so direct dependencies of your app will often have other dependencies

Answer (score 5):

Dotnet core tend to be very minimal as opposed to the previous versions of .net framework.

**In dotnet core, the main purpose was making the core framework as small as possible and if you need more stuff, bring it in through NuGet packages**.

So, many dependencies that used to be available in the framework are now moved to the NuGet packages and as you know there is a chain of dependencies in NuGet packages, so we will end up with so many libraries in our publish output, which is fine.

Another point being, most of the time, we're using project templates with too many dependencies that might not be needed whatsoever. So we can either start with a very minimal template and add needed stuff in it, or remove useless stuff from a more chuncky template.

Comment: Is there a way to put all those Nuget packages dlls under a folder named for example bin???

Comment: Any documentation on this?

Comment: this doc's somehow relevant :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/packages
as you see using **metapackages** is another alternative.

Comment: @akazemis Can you explain why it's not recommended to put these files in bin?  I don't see the answer on the link you provided.

Comment: @mrcoulson the link I mentioned is not about directly copying dlls it's more about how the dependencies should be handled in dotnet core. the reason why we should not copy directly and use the nuget packages, is that through the nuget packages the versioning/compatibility, dependencies and upgrading could be handled easily in an organized manner. it's up to you if you need such things then using Nuget packages would be your choice otherwise you can go for the copying dll approach

Comment: This answer doesn't address why they're in the ROOT of the web folder, not in the BIN folder where they belong! -1

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. When my local computer was upgraded from Net Core 2.0 to 2.1, my Core We Application which references a NetStandard application started publishing all DLL's in all referenced projects. I migrated my Core 2.0 application to 2.1 to match the highest version of SDK installed on my local and I could see my issue is now resolved. Publishing from the migrated(upgraded) application produced only the required DLL's. Hope this helps.

Comment: even I installed vs 2019 which installed .net core SDK  2.1. And my project's framework was in 2.0. I uninstalled the 2.1 SDK and published my web api application again and yes it did not generate any unnecessary dlls..thanks for the suggestion